# Do I need to have a blank DVD in order to install Solaris 10 on my VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm planning to run Solaris 10 on a VirtualBox VM(on my windows machine). I'm [downloading the link from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp)

So do I need a blank DVD  in order to install this onto my VirtualBox? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blank DVD is not necessary.
use Virtual DVD device can install.

Comment: Is the prog. called Virtual DVD? i googled and found a few ones

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBoxMethod 4 of 5: Set The CD To Start